# unicode url in cms pages, how?

Tags: magento, url, magento-1.9.1

How can I have unicode (etc UTF-8) URL key for CMS pages , products and category in magento ?

for Example : http://example.com/product/mobile1.html to http://example.com/موبایل1/محصول.html

Regards .

Answer (score 1):

By default Magento dose not support using unicode characters as a URL key, Magento will replace every non-Latin character with a latin one.

You could try this tutorial: http://rakan.me/2012/07/19/support-unicode-in-magento-product-url-key/

Otherwise, there are however some extensions that will allow you to use unicode - have a google.